# How does Flash Player execute Timer?

Tags: optimization, air, flash

I know about *runtime code execution fundamentals* in Flash Player and Air Debugger. But I want to know how Timer code execution is done.
Would it be better to use Timer rather than enterFrame event for similar actions? Which one is better to maximize optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to use it for. Most will vehemently say to use `Event.ENTER_FRAME`. In most instances, this is what you want. It will only be called once every frame begins construction. If your app is running at 24fps (the default), that code will run once every 41.7ms, assuming no dropped frames. For almost all GUI related cases, you do not want to run that code more often than this because it is entirely unnecessary (you can run it more often, sure, but it won't do any good since the screen is only updated that often).

There are times when you need code to run more often, however, mostly in non-GUI related cases. This can range from a systems check that needs to happen in the background to something that needs to be absolutely precise, such as an object that needs to be displayed/updated on an exact interval (Timer is accurate to the ms, I believe, whereas ENTER_FRAME is only accurate to the 1000/framerate ms).

In the end, it doesn't make much sense to use Timer for anything less than ENTER_FRAME would be called. Any more than that and you risk dropping frames. ENTER_FRAME is ideal for nearly everything graphics related, other than making something appear/update at a precise time. And even then, you should use ENTER_FRAME as well since it would only be rendered in the next frame anyway.

You need to evaluate each situation on a case-by-case basis and determine which is best for that particular situation because there is no best answer for all cases.

**EDIT**

I threw together a quick test app to see when Timer fires. Framerate is 24fps (42ms) and I set the timer to run every 10ms. Here is a selection of times it ran at.

```
2121
2137
2154
2171
2188
2203
2221
2237
```

As you can see, it is running every 15-18ms instead of the 10ms I wanted it to. I also tested 20ms, 100ms, 200ms, and 1000ms. In the end, each one fired within about 10ms of when it should have. So this is not nearly as precise as I had originally thought it was.

Comment: Thank you @JoshJanusch , and how is Timer code execution done? in every frame loop or just when it needs to be executed?

Comment: It appears that the `Timer` will fire close to the `ENTER_FRAME` event, but does not rely on it. So you cannot make it first much more often than `ENTER_FRAME`, but it can be fired somewhat quicker. You could test this yourself by setting up a Timer and seeing how close to the `delay` it fires by tracing out `getTimer()`

Comment: @yaa110 Please see the Edit I just made to my answer

Comment: I think documentation for Timer says that you shouldn't use Timer for intervals shorter than 16ms (roughly 60fps) because it will be unreliable.

Comment: @jpop My quick test seems to show that, but there is more. It appears that Timer executes as close to ENTER_FRAME as possible. On 24fps (41.7ms), setting it to a multiple of 43 sees variance of 30-40ms. Setting it to 40ms sees it within 1-2ms each time. From these results, it would seem that Timer is not accurate at all (as I had originally believed)