# Draggable menu for android and iphone as3

Tags: actionscript-3, menu, air, scroll

I would like to make a drag able menu like the instragram and other apps 
i tried to make a gradable ball that is follow my finger/ mouse on the x axis and then can be thrown on stage however, it's not working on my android, i don't understand it's pure mathematics and should work, i tried to twick any of the values but with no success
any suggestions why it's not working?
thank you

```
 package 
    {
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import flash.events.TimerEvent;
        import flash.geom.Rectangle;
        import flash.utils.Timer;
        import flash.geom.Point;
        /**
         * ...
         * @author 
         */
        public class GravityCoinsMain extends Sprite 
        {
            private var theCoin:Coin;
            private var deltaX:Number = 0;
            private var prevX:Number = 0;
            private var newX:Number = 0;
            private var PCControl:Boolean = true;
            private var speedLimit:Number = 15;     
            private var timer:Timer = new Timer(10);
            private var dragFactor:Number = 0.97;   

            private function update(te:TimerEvent):void
            {
                if (PCControl)
                {
                    if (theCoin.x > 0 && (theCoin.x < stage.stageWidth))
                    {
                        theCoin.x += deltaX;
                        deltaX *= dragFactor;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    prevX = newX;
                    newX = theCoin.x;
                    deltaX = newX - prevX;
                    var speed:Number =  deltaX ;

                    if ( speed > speedLimit )
                    {
                        deltaX *= speedLimit / speed;
                    }
                }
            }

            private function beginDrag(me:MouseEvent):void
            {
                theCoin.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(0,theCoin.y,5000,0));
                PCControl = false;
                timer.start();
            }

            private function endDrag(me:MouseEvent):void
            {
                theCoin.stopDrag();
                PCControl = true;
            }

            public function GravityCoinsMain()
            {



                theCoin = new Coin();
                addChild(theCoin);
                theCoin.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
                theCoin.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
                theCoin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, beginDrag);
                theCoin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, endDrag);

                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, update);

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I suggest looking at the ThrowProps plugin from Greensock. It's not available for free, but it allows for velocity and friction based movement. I used it to create my own scroller earlier this year and it actually felt better than the Flex scroller. You should be able to use it for this purpose (or at least its principles and example code, anyway)

Comment: Thank you, these guys want quite a lot for their class, however take a look at my example it's working great on desktop why noton my mobile?

Comment: Yeah, the plugin is expensive. But the library is among the best out there. At least look at the example code for their scroller. That said, the only thing I see that is out of place (other than some poor class structure) is the `MOUSE_UP` listener should be attached to the stage, not the coin, and added in the `MOUSE_DOWN` handler.

Comment: i think that i find the problem, it seems that the phones are faster then the desktop (i know it sounds odd...) but it i will change the timer delay from 10 to 50 it will work great. i really dont know why but it just that!

Comment: See my answer here and the comments on it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877369/how-does-flash-player-execute-timer/17886378#17886378